# Access to return value from Task (C#)

Tags: c#, async-await, return, task

I got method:

```
class C1
{
  private async Task OpenCar()    
 {
   ...
    await p.ReopenNewDoor(x, y);
    return //false or true
  }
}
```

Then:

```
class C1
{
  public Task ReopenNewDoor(int x, int y)
  {
     return mvvm.DoSomething(x,y)
  }      
}
```

And:

```
class C3
{
  internal async Task<bool> DoSomething(int x, int y)
  {
    .....
    if(a = b) return false;
    ....
    if(z!) return true;
  }
}
```

How can I know what will return `ReopenNewDoor`? `(true or false)`

Comment: Well, you don't have to return anything; `private async Task OpenCar() {... await p.ReopenNewDoor(x, y);}`

Comment: You should declare the return type ofr `ReopenNewDoor` as `Task<bool>` and use `Result` property, or simply `await` for it

Answer (score 0):

```
class C1
{
  private async Task<bool> OpenCar()    
  {
   ...
    var result = await p.ReopenNewDoor(x, y);
    return result;
  }
}
```

If this not working, you can access result of task using

> p.ReopenNewDoor(x, y).Result;

Comment: `result` is `bool` not `Task`.

Comment: really? then must update method header: private async Task OpenCar

Comment: It should be `private async Task<bool> OpenCar()`

Comment: yes. but the body is the same.  Can read result of task using Result then

Comment: There's no need to access `.Result` because `await` unwraps the result for you. `await p.ReopenNewDoor(x, y).Result;` will not compile either, because `Result` is `bool`, so you are trying to `await` a `bool`.